# Glass Mapper v5 Item creation issue

Tags: glass-mapper

I'm using Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 with Glass Mapper.Sc version 5.2.13

I'm trying to create items in Sitecore using GlassMapper and the following code

```
repository.RequestContext.SitecoreService.CreateItem(parent, model);
```

But I get this error:

> Type 'MyModel' does not have a Template ID or Branch ID.

`MyModel` is decorated with the `[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{my-model-template-guid}", AutoMap = true)]` attribute and inherits from a base class that has a TemplateId property defined as

```
[SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateId)]
public virtual Guid TemplateId { get; set; }
```

but it does not have the `'[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{base-class-template-guid}", AutoMap = true)]'` defined ... could be this the issue ? If I try creating items based on the base class model it works just fine.

All `MyModel's` properties are virtual but it seems to me the GlassMapper does not read the TemplateId specified as attribute.

Has anyone experienced this?

### Update: Adding Model Classes:

Please see the model code below

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{AA1DE664-7E99-4ACB-8DB4-EBA8C3F0693E}", AutoMap = true)]
public class MyModel : GlassMapperBase
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "First Name")]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Last Name")]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And the base class code together with the interface it implements:

```
public class GlassMapperBase : IGlassMapperBase
{
        [SitecoreId]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Version)]
        public virtual int Version { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Language)]
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.ContentPath)]
        public virtual string ContentPath { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.FullPath)]
        public virtual string FullPath { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Url)]
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.DisplayName)]
        public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateName)]
        public virtual string TemplateName { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.TemplateId)]
        public virtual Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

}

public interface IGlassMapperBase
{
    [SitecoreId]
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Version)]
    int Version { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Language)]
    Language Language { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add code snippets of your model classes to your question?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error, but here is a suggestion. Just use the Sitecore API to create the item. Don't bother with Glass for that. It will be quicker to write and you won't get cryptic errors like this.